# Proposing new initiative (in this case for data analysis)

Tags: software-industry, new-job, change-agency

I am starting a new role, that is (technically) not IT related. I would really like to enhance what's going on with this team by building some dashboards to get around using some of the archaic reporting tools so much. Right now there are at least 6 different reporting tools for similar data that all give you different numbers. I imagine I'll be querying OLAP cubes to do this but my experience in this area is limited. The IT department is a total mess from the outside looking in.

How do I approach my IT department and request access to the data warehouse/SSaS server(s) so that I can set up my own OLAP cube(s) or gain access to ones already made. No one at the company has even been able to explain the infrastructure of the data to me.

My big data experience is beginner level like I said but I imagine it is something like Oracle cloud data and hadoop. Do I just ask about to infrastructure to a VP and go from there? How do I word this so that I don't sound like an idiot, I will definitely be learning as I go but am confident in my ability there. I can justify the business need, the data will be safe.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated on how to word things and make the approach, etc. Thank you.

Comment: "How do I word this so that I don't sound like an idiot, I will definitely be learning as I go" and "the data will be safe" are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Ask for read-only access, not write-access. What's your current non-IT role? Is there an excuse your job could give you to have access to that data?

Comment: Financial Analyst... so it shouldnt be as hard as it has been? I will probably need to set up the SSaS cubes myself. I mean the server would be a company server and theyd have their usual security protocols in place,

Comment: "So it shouldn't be as hard as it has been?" You mean you tried to get the access before? If so what did you ask and what was the response?

Comment: No one knows lol. I haven't gotten a direct no. I just haven't gone up high enough I suppose.

Comment: You say that your experience is limited, your experience is beginner level like, and you will learn as you go. Are you sure you will actually be able to make this thing work?

Comment: All I'm trying to do to start is run some MDX into a Power BI or Tableau. I have programming experience (including SQL, just not massive data warehouses powered by hadoop) Technically I already have access to the data it is just through reporting tools so if I wanted to waste 12 years of my life I could build what I need myself.

Comment: Is there any reason you would not ask your direct manager to clear it with IT?

Comment: @gary93 If you need 12 years to build it, then you either don't know what you are doing or you are working on something that no one will need.

Comment: @UchihaMadara I don't think you understood what I said at all. The reporting tools in place give me the access to the data I need but have a limit of 250k rows that can be pulled hence the 12 years hyperbole. Maybe a helpful answer instead of irrelevant comments?

Comment: waiting for the reverse question _"How do I deal with a persistent, non-technical user approaching me with buzzword soup and asking for access which he has no business having?"_

Comment: Haha I can see this happening, I think buzzword soup is strong. I do have a decent idea of what I want to do and how to do it I've just never done it before. My big data background is limited, my technical background is more than adequate for this project. Plus I'd be asking for sales data... I am a financial analyst... I  think "no business" having access is strong.

Comment: @gary93 Yes, I didn't understand because I am not good at reading strangers' minds over the internet. I was hoping to give you a helpful answer and asked you questions to understand your situation more clearly. Perhaps you should avoid using confusing hyperboles if you want a helpful answer. I was asking you those questions because if you aren't confident about what you propose, people won't be convinced to cooperate with you. I wanted to make sure if that was indeed the case, so I could help you accordingly. Anyway, what you do with your tools and dashboard doesn't concern me. You do you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How do you approach this? It sounds like you have no idea whether your idea will be welcome.  It might be very unwelcome, especially in a chaotic IT environment. People can be extremely possessive of their data.

You have to **sell** this idea to your company. Selling this kind of idea to companies generally requires somebody in the company to serve as a **champion** for the idea. You personally are too new to serve as the champion.  Your champion needs to have enough clout to tell your IT people your idea is a priority.

Your first step is to write a short (no more than 300 words) document describing the **benefits -- to the company** -- of your project.  This document is for you. It will help you get clarity about what you want to sell.  Answer two questions: **what** and **why.** Skip over when, where, and how. Boil it down. Simplify it. ONE power-point slide. ONLY ONE. Work out your [elevator pitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elevator_pitch). (The time for a more complete proposal is later.)

Your second step is to show it to somebody in the company you trust. "I have an idea, what do you think?"  Perhaps this is your direct supervisor, a co-worker, or even a friend in the IT area.  Work with that person to **refine** your idea. Ask "can you introduce me to somebody else who might have good suggestions about this?"  By talking to people you can identify a champion. You'll also find out whether something similar already exists.  Hint: VPs make good champions.

Your third step, once you have a champion, is to ask for advice about how to make your project happen. Your champion may not know about the electropolitical hurdles, so you need to find someone who does.

If you get all the way through these three steps, you'll be in a position to go forward.

If you can't get through them all, don't be too disappointed. Certainly don't be annoyed. You'll still learn a lot about your organization and what it takes to do new things.

Keep in mind that **selling ideas to companies is hard work and can take a long time**. Don't expect people to jump on your idea immediately and help you push it through. Even your friends will need time (days or weeks) to absorb it and make it their own.

And, you will need to share the credit: certainly with your supervisor and your champion, and maybe others.

(And, please please please make sure any databases / warehouses / cubes you create are correctly secured against cybercreeps.)

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like classic new person syndrome. "I'm going to change the world!"

You've mentioned a few things that give me pause:

1. You're new to the company.
2. You don't exactly have the required experience to do what it is that you want to do.

My advice would be to take some time to learn the company, the culture, and the existing tools before you start ruffling feathers. There's probably a great deal that you are unaware of and you most certainly lack any real insight into the internal mechanisms that make the company "go". Don't be too eager to "shake things up". That's rarely welcome from new-comers. As a first step, why don't you use the tools that are available to you and determine their effectiveness in getting the data you need for doing your job? If you find them lacking then compile a list of things you think you can do to make them better and present them to your boss. You'll need his/her buy in and approval and you'll most certainly need the cooperation of the IT department in order to get what you're proposing.

Comment: I understand why you would think that but I am new to the role, not the company. I understand what is needed to help the team (via observation and verbal expression of other team members including managers) and am looking to execute on it. Thank you though.

Comment: Ah, I shouldn't have assumed that you were new to the company. My advice then... go forward, but tread lightly and respectfully.